# Android how to change the button color by the text

Tags: android, css, colors, background, drawable

I simply wish to change the background color of the button by the value of the text. For example, when I change the text to:

```
button.setText("YES");
```

I want to set the background color of the button to ***green***.
and when I change the text to:

```
button.setText("NO");
```

I want to set the background color of the button to ***red***.

When I change it in the java code like this:

```
boolean textValueYES = true;
button.setBackgroundColor(textValueYES ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
```

The button loses its drawable.xml settings.
Is there a way to add this checking to the drawable xml?
Or to set the background color by its text value without losing the drawable settings?

Comment: To set your button background as drawable use `button.setBackgroundResource(textValueYES ? R.drawable.greendrawable : R.drawable.reddrawable);`

Comment: create drawable file with red background color and green background color like: red_drawable.xml, green_drawable.xml, and use button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_drawable);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create two drawable xml for red and green background color and set that xml programmatically.

```
button.setBackgroundResource(textValueYES ? R.drawable.green : R.drawable.red);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do like this just write below of setText()

i.e

```
button.setText("YES");
setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
```

and when

```
button.setText("NO");
setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

Answer (score 1):

i do like this in my java file

```
    final Button btn_showtouch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_showtouch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if((btn_showtouch.getText()).equals("YES")) {
                btn_showtouch.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                btn_showtouch.setText("NO");
            }else if(btn_showtouch.getText().equals("NO")) {
                btn_showtouch.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                btn_showtouch.setText("YES");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

and your XML file like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YES"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
```

and its worked for me i hope this will help you